# Rendering Foreign Keys in templates grouped by origin

Tags: django

I have an Area model, and I have Service model. Area is a Foreignkey of Service.

I want a template which shows each Service grouped under its respective Area, i.e.

`Area 1`

`- service a`

`- service b`

`Area 2`

`- etc.`

I've passed in an object list of all services to `service_list.html`. I have a custom tag `get_areas` which returns the areas, on which I can create the Area divisions, and from which I can potentially pass an area name to a service filter. But since I can't filter (can I?) in `{% for service in object_list %}`, how can I filter the service list in each Area's section of the HTML?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your models I can give you the exact code, but in general something like this should work:

```
# Pass in 'areas' variable from view with all required areas

{% for  area in areas %}
    {{ area.name }}
    {% for service in area.service_set.all %} #Gets all the services associated with an area
        {{ service.name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endofor %}
```

Not sure you even need a custom tag, but maybe I just don't understand that part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the regroup template tag. It was built for exactly the same purpose
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

One thing that I have realized is that once you get the point of displaying complex interrelated data in your templates, that it makes sense to transform the data into an appropriate object (generally a list of dictionaries) before passing them onto the template.

That way, you can test your information easier, and have a much easier time displaying it. (You'll have much powerful tools at your disposition in Python based Views than in Django Templating Language).

Comment: Great, thanks! May I follow up? The method depends on the ordering. I haven't explicitly set ordering anywhere so I presume this is currently luck - where is that determined? And I expected to have to account for the difference between the example you point to and my case being that I have a foreign key where they have a text string. I expected to have to explicitly retrieve the Area's name, yet it just showed up. I presume this is a property of Foreignkey?

Answer (score 0):

@Maz - thank you for that. I'm learning at the moment and need to look at `service_set`.

@arustgi - that worked perfectly. For the benefit of fellow novices stumbling over this, I pass in `'queryset': Service.objects.all()` and use:

```
    {% regroup object_list by area as area_list %}
    {% for area in area_list %}
        <h2 class="separate">{{ area.grouper }}</h2>
        {% for service in area.list %}
        <div class="column">
            <h3>{{ service.title }}</h3>
            {{ service.body }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Concise, descriptive code. Many thanks, both of you